# Extracting values from multiple raster dataset at location point in one single dbf using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point

Suppose I have 250 raster and my only concern is just a single point. The raster is arranged by ascending date. So if I extract a point value based on the order into one single file then I can graph it just easily.

How do I do it using ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 2):

The [extract multi values to points](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000002s000000.htm) tool is for this exact situation. The fact that you have only a single point is irrelevant, unless you have it in a feature class with other points. Then, of course, just select it and export it to a new feature class or set a definition query on your layer before running the tool.